# Check my local ip with a path whether it is valid or not

Tags: c#, ip

Hello  i try to check if my ip (on a local server) is valid or not and add a path to it, but the problem is that it is not considered an ip address while when I test "192.168.0.235/cmd.html?c-31" it is well displayed on my browser. here's the code:

```
public static bool check_ip(string ip)
{
    //192.168.0.235/cmd.html?c=31
    string path_ip = ip + "/cmd.html?c=31"; // error not an ip
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("path_ip");
    PingReply pong = ping.Send(address, 100);
    if (pong.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

how can i make my function check an ip with a path (ex: "192.168.0.235/cmd.html?c-31")?

Comment: You seem confused as to what an IP is. Your IP is 192.168.0.235, no letters attached. Pinging that gives you no information whether your service is running. You are better of using an HttpClient as @AthanasiosKataras suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only check the ip part:

```
        public static bool check_ip(string ip)
        {
                //192.168.0.235/cmd.html?c=31
                string path_ip = ip + "/cmd.html?c=31"; // error not an ip
                Ping ping = new Ping();
                IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
                PingReply pong = ping.Send(address, 100);
                if (pong.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
        }
```

Beware for lines like this:

```
// "path_ip" is not the value of your variable, but a string value "path_ip"
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("path_ip");
```

If you want ot check a url as if it was a browser:

```
using var client = new HttpClient();

var result = await client.GetAsync("http://192.168.0.235/cmd.html?c=31");
Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode); // if the status code is in the 2XX range, you are ok.
```

Comment: No i need to check the ip with this path "/cmd.html?c=31" for know if it's my Device or not.

Comment: The ip is unique in your network. The rest of it is just a url. You are effectively checking if a url responds in yout browser and not the ip itself. If you want to check an ip, then that's the way to do it. If you want to see if the url responds, then use an `HttpClient`